# The integral of a multivariable Dirac delta function

Tags: integration

Does anybody know how to perform the following integral analytically:
\begin{equation}
I=\int^\infty_{eV/2} d\epsilon_1 \int_{-\infty}^{-eV/2} d\epsilon_2 \int^\infty_{0} d\epsilon' \int_{-\infty}^{0} d\epsilon\,\delta(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1+\epsilon-\epsilon')
\end{equation}
Above $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac's delta function.

I have used Mathematica to do this, and it gives me $I = -\frac{(eV)^3}{6}$.

Comment: Have you tried anything beyond Mathematica? What have you attempted on your own to answer this?

Comment: Also, I am getting $0$ for the integral if $eV>0$

Answer (score 2):

The Dirac delta returns $1$ if its argument vanishes within the interval of integration, or zero otherwise. Doing this for the innermost integral, we get
$$
I
=\int^\infty_{eV/2} d\epsilon_1 \int_{-\infty}^{-eV/2} d\epsilon_2 \int^\infty_{0} d\epsilon^\prime \, \theta(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1-\epsilon^\prime)
,
$$
in terms of the Heaviside theta function (i.e. $\theta(x)=1$ for $x>0$, $\theta(x)=0$ for $x<0$), because if $\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1-\epsilon^\prime<0$ is positive then there exists an $\epsilon<0$ such that $\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1+\epsilon-\epsilon^\prime=0$, and if it's negative, then $\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1+\epsilon-\epsilon^\prime<0$ for all negative $\epsilon$.

Pushing on, if $\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1$ is negative, then $\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1-\epsilon^\prime$ for all $\epsilon^\prime>0$, so the integral comes to zero, while if it is positive then the integral effectively runs for $\epsilon^\prime\in[0,\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1]$, which means that we can write
\begin{align}
I
& =
\int^\infty_{eV/2} d\epsilon_1 \int_{-\infty}^{-eV/2} d\epsilon_2 \theta(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1) \int^{\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1}_{0} d\epsilon^\prime 
\\ & =
\int^\infty_{eV/2} d\epsilon_1 \int_{-\infty}^{-eV/2} d\epsilon_2 
(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)
\ \theta(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)
.
\end{align}

Furthermore, for any given $\epsilon_1>eV/2$, the $\epsilon_2$ integrand vanishes whenever $\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1<0$, i.e. when $\epsilon_2<\epsilon_1$, so we can get rid of the theta function and substitute in $\epsilon_1$ as the lower integral limit:
\begin{align}
I
& =
\int^\infty_{eV/2} d\epsilon_1 
\theta(-eV/2-\epsilon_1)
\int_{\epsilon_1}^{-eV/2} d\epsilon_2\,
(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)
,
\end{align}
with the remaining theta function indicating that if $\epsilon_1> -eV/2$ the previous theta-function integration $\int_{-\infty}^{-eV/2} d\epsilon_2 \theta(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1) \cdots$ has a vanishing integral throughout its domain.

Finally, to get rid of the theta functions in the integrand altogether, we note that for the integral to integrate to anything nonzero, there needs to be a range of $\epsilon_1$ such that both $-eV/2-\epsilon_1> 0$ and $\epsilon_1>eV/2$, or in other words
$$
\frac12 eV < \epsilon_1 < -\frac12 eV,
$$
which can only be the case if $eV<0$. To express this simply, just add one final theta function on the outside:
\begin{align}
I
& =
\theta(-eV)
\int^\infty_{eV/2} 
\int_{\epsilon_1}^{-eV/2}
(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)
\,d\epsilon_2
\,d\epsilon_1 
.
\end{align}

The rest is just clean integration as usual.

Answer (score 0):

E.P., thank you for your answer. Integrating out the first variableis the most crucial step. When I was solving this problem, I first tried to reduce the multivariable Dirac delta to a single-variable one. At the end, it became very difficult to analyze that under which circumstance does the Dirac delta become nonzero.

In the following, I start with the last equation and finish the rest of the calcuations:

\begin{equation}
I =  \int^{\infty}_{eV/2}d\epsilon_1 \int^{-eV/2}_{\epsilon_1}d\epsilon_2(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)
\end{equation} 
Here, $\epsilon_1$ becomes the lower bound of $\epsilon_2$, indicating that $\epsilon_1 \leq -eV/2$. Thus, we should change the range of the integration over $\epsilon_1$ above accordingly, i.e.
\begin{equation}
I =  \int^{-eV/2}_{eV/2}d\epsilon_1 \int^{-eV/2}_{\epsilon_1}d\epsilon_2(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)=\int^{-eV/2}_{eV/2}d\epsilon_1  \left[\frac{(eV)^2}{8}+\frac{\epsilon_1^2}{2} + \frac{eV}{2}\epsilon_1\right]=-\frac{(eV)^3}{6}.\quad Q.E.D.
\end{equation} 
Thanks!

Comment: No, that's still not right - it returns the correct value if $eV<0$, but it does nothing to enforce that. Note that the initial integral has a positive integrand over positively-ordered intervals, which means that the value of the integral cannot be negative.